# C++ debugging with gdb & bazel (& emacs)

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb, bazel

I want to debug an executable generated with Bazel. The gdb debugger is lost with the links generated by Bazel and is not able to show me the C++ source code. How to fix that?

The project root directory is */home/.../Cpp/*

```
./Cpp/
├── bazel-bin -> /home/picaud/.cache/bazel/_bazel_picaud...
├── bazel-Cpp -> /home/picaud/.cache/bazel/_bazel_picaud...
├── bazel-genfiles -> /home/picaud/.cache/bazel/_bazel_picaud...  
├── bazel-out -> /home/picaud/.cache/bazel/_bazel_picaud...   
├── bin
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── main.cpp
├── MyLib
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── ....hpp
│   ├──  ...cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The **first step** is to generate executables using the debug mode:

```
bazel build ... --compilation_mode=dbg --subcommands
```

(the `--subcommands` option is not mandatory it only shows the executed commands, you can remove it if you want)

**gdb debugging from the command line:**

You can start *gdb* with **this** command (from your project root directory):

```
gdbtui bazel-bin/bin/main
```

-> everything is okay, you should see your C++ source code.

The **error would be to do**:

```
cd bazel-bin/bin/
gdbtui main
```

In that case, because of the links, gdb is not able to retrieve the source code.

**gdb debugging from Emacs:**

Do as usual

```
M-x gdb
```

In the emacs prompt define the complete absolute path to the executable:

```
gdb -i=mi /home/picaud/.../Cpp/bazel-bin/bin/main
```

Now in the **gdb buffer** you must tell gdb where to find source by defining your absolute path to the project root directory (where your WORKSPACE file is):

```
set directories /home/picaud/.../Cpp
```

Now the emacs gdb command should work properly and you can debug as usual.

(well this was an easy fix, just a note that maybe can help...)

Comment: I've tried something pretty similar to this but gdb couldn't find files whose paths started with `external/...`. I ended up starting in `bazel-<dirname>` (In this case, it'd be `bazel-Cpp`). It seemed that all source paths were correct when starting in that dir.

Comment: That comment is real answer to the question!

Comment: hi Picaud Vincent, you have any configs for setting up debugging a Bazel project on CLion IDE (version 2020.1.3, ubuntu) with the Bazel plugin? ...Thanks in advance!

Comment: @drstoop no sorry, I cannot help there: I have never used CLion IDE nor have access to it.

Comment: @PicaudVincent you are the wind beneath my wings.  Many thanks!