# GDB quits instantly when invoking bazel command for debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, bazel

I found two links showing how debugging with gdb under bazel should work ([link 1](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/312), [link 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/Mu95dnuA2MQ)).

Both links state that launching a debug session works when invoking the following command:

`bazel run --compilation_mode=dbg --run_under=gdb //my:target`

When I run the command, gdb starts just fine, loading the symbols and everything, but then immediately quits. The output is the same as shown in [here (from link 2)](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/Mu95dnuA2MQ/v_HN7sixGAAJ).

The first link also mentions the `--direct_run`-argument, but this argument does not work either. gdb instantly quits and the following message, which is appended after the output of gdb (from the previous link), is shown:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.ISO-8859-1",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.ISO-8859-1",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.ISO-8859-1",
        LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.ISO-8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I interact with gdb?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your bazel version?

Comment: @TillBrychcy version is 0.13.0

Comment: As an alternative, maybe you can try this procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812725/c-debugging-with-gdb-bazel-emacs/45812726#45812726

Comment: @PicaudVincent That was my initial way of debugging, but it was kind of cumbersome. Take a look at the reply I have posted under Tom Tromeys answer. Maybe you're interested in that script aswell. Can be invoked like this: `./bazel-run.sh --compilation_mode=dbg --run_under=gdb //my:target`

Comment: @MikevanDyke thanks for the clarification, I will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another message in that thread (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/Mu95dnuA2MQ/I2BDu0SDGAAJ) points out that bazel doesn't pass the tty to gdb's stdin.  What you are seeing is what you would expect if you invoke gdb without stdin attached:

```
$ gdb -silent -nx  < /dev/null
(gdb) quit
```

One option for a workaround might be to write a wrapper script that invokes `gdb < /dev/tty`.

Comment: you're right about that. Tt pointed me into the right direction and I found the following script: [bazel-run.sh](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/scripts/bazel-run.sh). This script allows interaction with gdb. I'm not going to accept your answer right away, in case someone has a better option.